# Об артиклях

Tags: лингвистика

Во многих языках, даже некоторых славянских (насколько я знаю, например, в болгарском) есть артикли. Причем, в некоторых, этих артиклей очень много (например, в испанском), а в русском нет никаких. Зачем вообще нужны артикли и почему их нет в русском?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Довольно странно отвечать на вопросы "Почему?" когда дело касается некоей данности, каковой и является русский язык. Ну добро бы ещё "Как получилось?" или "Куда они делись?" А на "почему" хочется ответить "потому, что их нет".

Мне не кажется, что рассуждения о грамматическом строе языка (сами по себе безусловно верные) дают исчерпывающий ответ на проблему артикля. В английском грамматическая роль артикля сведена почти на нет, а те функции, которые он выполняет (определённость-неопределённость, маркер существительного и т.п.) никак со строем языка не связаны. В русском для этого просто нет средств, вряд ли это связано с грамматическим строем. Зато в болгарском артикль берет на себя определённую грамматическую роль - склоняемой части (что в современном болгарском, где в активном использовании сохранились только два падежа, очень немаловажно). Поэтому говорить о какой-то принципиальной единой роли артикля для всех языков - и выяснять, почему он есть в одних и отсутвует в других, не приходится.

И самое главное. В русском языке... есть артикль. Очень, кстати, похожий по своей роли и своей организации на болгарский. Только "пришивается" он не к существительным, как в болгарском, а к прилагательным. Если сравнить современные краткие прилагательные с полными, то "разница" как раз и будет артиклем. Красен - Красн**ый**, Горяча - Горяча**я**, Велико - Велико**е** и т.д.
Исходно это древнерусские указательные местоимения И, Я и Е, близкие по значению к современным "тот", "та" и "то", а по функции к личным местоимениям "он", "она" и "оно" (а в косвенных падежах и совпадающие с последними). Для множенственного числа там дело чуть посложнее, но суть та же. Эти местоимения в русском по сути выполняли роль артикля. Впоследствии они потеряли смысловое значение и стали восприниматься как часть прилагательного.

Это очень примитивное изложение, знатоки, наверное, упрекнут за недоговорки. Но полностью излагать тут всё нет никаой возможности.

Comment: Абсолютно согласна, что дать исчерпывающий ответ на вопрос "почему?" не представляется возможным. На данную тему, думается, можно диссертацию написать :-)

Answer (score 1):

Артикль - служебное слово (частица) или аффикс, употребляющиеся в некоторых языках при существительном для определения его рода, выражения определенности-неопреледенности именных категорий. Исторически определенный артикль восходит к указательному местоимению, неопределенный артикль - к неопределенному местоимению или числительному *один*. 
Артикли чаще всего имеются в языках аналитического строя, т.е. а таких языках, где основными средствами выражения грамматических отношений являются служебные слова (например, предлоги, артикли) и порядок слов. Например, в немецком языке (аналитико-синтетический строй) род и падеж существительного показываются преимущественно аналитически (т.е. с помощью артикля или его эквивалента). В русском же языке (а это язык синтетического строя: грамматические отношения выражаются при помощи суффиксов, окончаний, т.е морфем, входящих в состав слова) те же грамматические категории передаются с помощью окончаний, т.е. внутри одного слова. Поэтому в русском языке артикли не нужны. Категория определенности-неопределенности у нас выражается (если это нужно) указательными (*этот, тот*) или неопределенными (*какой-то, некий*) местоимениями.

Болгарский язык, к слову, является аналитическим, существительные в нем не склоняются, поэтому артикль нужен для передачи грамматических форм существительного. В испанском языке артиклей не так уж много: определенный, неопределенный и нулевой (т.е. всего три).